# How to list all files in a git sparse-checkout?

Tags: git

How does `git ls-files` and `git sparse-checkout` behave together?

After doing a sparse checkout, I would like to calculate the number of files. If I use `git ls-files | wc -l` it will give me the same number as if the full repo was checked out. Is this by design? How can I limit the `ls-files` to only list files that are checked out?

Answer (score 3):

Try `git ls-files -v | grep -e '^H' | wc -l`. The checked-out files are marked with a leading `H` and the hidden ones with `S`. But make sure the repository is clean. Files of other status have other leading letters.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but feels quite hacky.